# Weird nav controller behavior with different tab bar stacks

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a tab bar controller with a nav bar embedded in each tab as root. I am using a detail view controller that will be accessed from 2 of these tab bar stacks. When accessing this view controller in it's own stack, everything works as expected. However, if the user is in the other tab and segues to this detail view controller, the view slips behind the navigation bar. Its like the nav bar isn't even there, it just goes underneath it. I've been scratching my head trying to figure out what's going on, any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out for those in a similar predicament. Need to add `navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false` in `viewDidLoad`. In iOS 7 this changed, by adding this line it won't slide the view beneath the nav bar.